# Access a view in a fragment layout from outside class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to access a `TextView` from an outside class. The `TextView` is part of a `layout` inflated by a `fragment`. How do I achieve this? I cannot reference the fragment as I have 3 other fragments with different layouts.

EDIT :

I have this fragment where in I would like to access totalTxt :

```
public class FragmentCart extends Fragment {
    private TextView totalTxt;
    private ListView itemList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        itemList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemList);
        itemList.setAdapter(MainActivity.cart);
        return view;
    }
```

and I have this class

```
    public class someClass extends BaseAdapter {
         //everytime the data here is changed, I would like to update 
           the value of the totalTxt above from this class
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain question breifly or post your code

Comment: three fragment in same activity?

Comment: yea three fragment in same activity

Comment: ok where you use string from fragment? i mean use string from one fragment to  another fragment ?

Comment: are u using textview for set some string rite?

Comment: I updated my post with my problem

Comment: that mean you want to update the value of textview totalTxt from baseAdapter ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1.Go with Java Interface.

```
public interface MyListener {
    // you can define any parameter as per your requirement
    public void callback(View view, String result);
}
```

2.In your fragment Class:

```
 public class MyActivity extends fragment implements MyListener {
   @override        
   public void onCreate(){
        MyButton m = new MyButton(this);
   }

    // method is invoked when MyButton is clicked
    @override
    public void callback(View view, String result) {   
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

3.in your adapter Class:

```
public class someClass extends BaseAdapter implements MyListener {
         //everytime the data here is changed, I would like to update 
           the value of the totalTxt above from this class
    }
```

here 2 and 3 or optional where u want to share your data either fragment or baseAdapter .its your choice.i gave both example.let try via interface when value get upated

Let me Know is this okay or not.

Comment: No. I need to update totalTxt automatically when data changes. I need access to the view totalTxt, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

By providing a simple callback .

For this to work write a simple interface in your adapter

```
public interface OnDataChangeListener{
    public void onDataChanged(String value);
}
```

and add a setter for the listener (also in the adapter)

```
OnDataChangeListener mOnDataChangeListener;
public void setOnDataChangeListener(OnDataChangeListener onDataChangeListener){
    mOnDataChangeListener = onDataChangeListener;
}
```

now add additional code to the following block in the baseadapter

```
private void conditionOfValuechanged() {
    ...
    if(mOnDataChangeListener != null){
        mOnDataChangeListener.onDataChanged(data.size());
    }
}
```

in  activity you then need to register the listener

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    adapter.setOnDataChangeListener(new Sold_item_adaptor.OnDataChangeListener(){
        public void onDataChanged(String value){
            //do whatever here
             txtTotal.setText(value);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You lost me, sorry. I am getting a value from the adapter, and then setting that value to txtTotal

Comment: sorry about that ! but will try to help you , can you explain little more about the flow

Comment: you got value in the adapter , say 'hallo' &  from the adapter itself you need to access the textview [inside the fragment]  and set the value